# I need help. Seems like a basic tool that I cannot seem to find

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

Lets say I have some random text info that I have collected from subpar sources. The text consists of something as follows:

1st Floor - aklsl;asndgjasblgkbaskdbfjkabsdlkfbjla 2nd Floor - infoinfofino theoreticalinfo yasddadas 3rd Floor - more random stuff relevant to this floor, no consistency in the data etc.

and I want to put this into a string. So:

```
var string = "1st Floor - aklsl;asndgjasblgkbaskdbfjkabsdlkfbjla 2nd Floor - infoinfofino theoreticalinfo yasddadas 3rd Floor - more random stuff relevant to this floor, no consistency in the data etc.";
```

How do I split the string into an array based on the special characters "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "4th" etc. because there is no numerical pattern to the info after each floor.

I was thinking

```
var newString = string.split("1st" || "2nd" || "3rd");
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: Maybe using regex ?

Comment: use regular expression? string.split(/1st|2nd|3rd/)

Comment: That syntax with the ors is just a truthy check. It is just going to be the first thing that is truthy. Since the first one is truthy it will be `string.split("1st")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` with regex:

```js
var string = "1st Floor - aklsl;asndgjasblgkbaskdbfjkabsdlkfbjla 2nd Floor - infoinfofino theoreticalinfo yasddadas 3rd Floor - more random stuff relevant to this floor, no consistency in the data etc."; 

var result = string.split(/(1st|2nd|3rd)/);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what would I do if I wanted the character being used to signal the line break to also be included in the line? This breaks the "1st" off into a seperate line.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: var result = string.split(/(1st|2nd|3rd)/); console.log(result);      will return the string with those arguments actually removed from the string. How do i stop that

Comment: Well split remove them, what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a regex that could obtain `n Floors` instead of only some of them (1st, 2nd and 3rd)

```js
var string = "1st Floor - aklsl;asndgjasblgkbaskdbfjkabsdlkfbjla 2nd Floor - infoinfofino theoreticalinfo yasddadas 3rd Floor - more random stuff relevant to this floor, no consistency in the data etc."; 

var result = string.split(/[\d]+\w+\sFloor\s[-]\s/).filter(item => item.length > 1);
console.log(result);
```